# Python turtle Dragon Game obstacles pause

Tags: python, python-3.6, turtle-graphics

Why is my Dragon Game not working correctly? 
When the dragon jumps, the obstacle pauses.
I want that when then dragon jumps the 
obstacle keeps moving.
This is the same game as the Dragon Game found on the Internet where obstacles enter in one by one.  But it's not working properly.
What is the logic error?

[image]

```
import turtle
import random
import time

win = turtle.Screen()
win.title("Dragon game")
win.bgcolor("white")
win.setup(width=800, height=300)

base_line = turtle.Turtle()
base_line.speed(0)
base_line.back(300)
base_line.fd(600)

dragon = turtle.Turtle()
dragon.shape("square")
dragon.speed(0)
dragon.color("black")
dragon.penup()
dragon.goto(-250, 10)
dragon.pendown()
dragon.setheading(90)

dragon_state = "steady"
number_of_obstacles = 10

obstacles_list = []

for i in range(number_of_obstacles):
    obstacles_list.append(turtle.Turtle())


for i in obstacles_list:
    i.hideturtle()
    i.color("black")
    i.shape("square")
    i.shapesize(1, 2)

    i.penup()
    i.speed(0)
    i.setheading(90)

    i.setposition(400, 5)

    i.showturtle()


def jump_dragon():
    global dragon_state
    if dragon_state == "steady":
        dragon_state = "jump"
    dragon.penup()
    dragon.speed(1)
    x = dragon.xcor()
    y = dragon.ycor() + 90
    dragon.setposition(x, y)
    y = dragon.ycor() - 90

    dragon.setposition(x, y)

    dragon.showturtle()


win.listen()
win.onkey(jump_dragon, "space")
index = 0

while True:

    x = random.randint(300, 505)

    while index < 10:

        s = random.randint(1, 4)
        x = x - 10

        obstacles_list[index].penup()
        obstacles_list[index].speed(1)
        obstacles_list[index].goto(x, 5)

        if dragon.distance(obstacles_list[index]) < 20:
            dragon_state = "steady"
            obstacles_list[index].hideturtle()
            print("Collision", index)
            x = random.randint(300, 405)
            index += 1
        elif obstacles_list[index].xcor() < -290:
            obstacles_list[index].hideturtle()
            index += 1


win.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

> i want to that dragon jump but obstacle is keep moving

To do this we first toss your `while True:` which has no place in an event-driven world like turtle.  In its place we put a timer event that fires off on regular intervals.  Next, we break up the horizontal movement of the obstacle and vertical movement of the dragon into small, interlaced movements.  Below is my rework of your code based on the above -- I simplified your obstacle logic to keep this example simple:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def jump_dragon():
    global dragon_state, dragon_direction

    if dragon_state == "steady":
        dragon_state = "jump"
        dragon_direction = 1
        dragon.forward(10)

def play():
    global dragon_state, dragon_direction

    if dragon_state == "jump":
        dragon.forward(dragon_direction * 10)

        y = dragon.ycor()

        if y >= 100:
            dragon_direction *= -1
        elif y <= 10:
            dragon_state = "steady"

    obstacle.forward(10)

    if obstacle.xcor() < -290:
        obstacle.hideturtle()
        obstacle.goto(290, 20)
        obstacle.showturtle()
    elif dragon.distance(obstacle) < 20:
        print("Collision")
        obstacle.hideturtle()
        obstacle.goto(290, 20)
        obstacle.showturtle()

    win.ontimer(play, 75)

win = Screen()
win.title("Dragon game")
win.setup(width=800, height=300)

base_line = Turtle(visible=False)
base_line.speed('fastest')
base_line.back(300)
base_line.forward(600)

dragon = Turtle("square", visible=False)
dragon.speed('slow')
dragon.setheading(90)
dragon.penup()
dragon.goto(-250, 10)
dragon.showturtle()

dragon_state = "steady"
dragon_direction = 1

obstacle = Turtle("square", visible=False)
obstacle.shapesize(2, 1)
obstacle.speed('fastest')
obstacle.penup()
obstacle.setheading(180)
obstacle.setposition(290, 20)
obstacle.showturtle()

win.onkey(jump_dragon, "space")
win.listen()

play()

win.mainloop()
```

I also reworked other parts of the code for style and clarity.